# Whats is the limit of $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,a)}\frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2-y^2}$ for $a\ne0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

What is $\lim^{}_{(x,y) \rightarrow (a,a)} \frac{x^3-y^3 }{x^2-y^2}$ for $a\ne 0$? I have found that the limit coould be $\frac{3a}{2}$ to proof it I have come to the point where $\left|\frac{x^3-y^3 }{x^2-y^2}-\frac{3a}{2}\right| = \left|\frac{x^2+xy+y^2 }{x+y}-\frac{3a}{2}\right|\le \left|x+y-\frac{3a}{2}\right|$. I have to go to something like $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-a)^2}$ however I have no idea what to do from here.

Comment: I have used that as you might see

Comment: Yeah, brain death on my part.

Comment: Once you reduce the fraction you should just apply the appropriate limit laws.

Comment: It's not clear how you get your inequality, nor why it matters. It is not true that if $U<V$ then $|U-W|<|V-W|$.

Comment: In fact, the inequality is false.

Comment: According to my book i have to show that for a $\delta = \delta(\epsilon)$ the following is true $\left|f(x,y)-L\right|\le\epsilon$ and that $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2} \le \delta$ for L as the value of the limit and (a,b) being the point of the lmit (in my case this is (a,a). That is the reason whhy have used that inequality

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim^{}_{(x,y) \rightarrow (a,a)} \frac{x^3-y^3 }{x^2-y^2}=\lim^{}_{(x,y) \rightarrow (a,a)} \frac{(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2) }{(x-y)(x+y)}=\lim^{}_{(x,y) \rightarrow (a,a)} \frac{x^2+xy+y^2}{x+y}=\frac{3a}{2}$$

Comment: According to my book i have to show that for a $\delta = \delta(\epsilon)$ the following is true $\left|f(x,y)-L\right|\le\epsilon$ and that $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2} \le \delta$ for L as the value of the limit and (a,b) being the point of the lmit (in my case this is (a,a)